# Android base adapter on item click i want to retrieve the package name belongs to the application label in the next activity

Tags: android

i am trying to display the application name and icon using the base adapter to the list  in activity 1 as follows.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG_Name = "name";
    private static final String TAG_Logo = "logo";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView i = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        ListAdapter mAdapter = ListAdapter.getInstance();

        mAdapter.setAdapterData(this.getApplicationContext());
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        i.setText(String.valueOf(ListAdapter.getInstance().getCount()));

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 String a = ((TextView)
                 view.findViewById(R.id.text)).getText()
                 .toString();
                 int n = position;
                 Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)((ImageView)
                 view.findViewById(R.id.image))
                 .getDrawable()).getBitmap();

                 // Starting new intent
                 Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                 Application_Perm.class);

                 in.putExtra(TAG_Name, a);
                 in.putExtra(TAG_Logo, bitmap);
                 in.putExtra("TAG", n);
                 startActivity(in);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

But what i do not know is, when i want to display the package name in the activity 2. which i pass the on select application name and icon. **HERE I WANT TO DISPLAY THE PACKAGE NAME OF THE SELECTED APPLICATION NAME.**

```
public class Application_Perm extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG_Name = "name";
    private static final String TAG_Logo = "logo";
    String name;
    TextView pack;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.perm);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
        TextView app = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textpermapp);
        pack = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pa_info);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        name = intent.getStringExtra(TAG_Name);
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra(TAG_Logo);

        app.setText(name);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }

}
```

**baseadapter**

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static ListAdapter self = null;
    private Context context = null;
    private List<MyAppInfo> list = null;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater = null;

    private ListAdapter() {

    }

    public static ListAdapter getInstance() {
        if (self == null) {
            self = new ListAdapter();
        }

        return self;
    }

    public synchronized void setAdapterData(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
        list = new ArrayList<MyAppInfo>();
        generate();

    }

    private void generate() {
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm
                .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

        for (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : packages) {
            if ((applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 1) {

                list.add(new MyAppInfo("" + applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm),
                        applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm)));
            }
        }

    }

    public synchronized int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        MyAppInfo info = list.get(position);

        TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        text.setText(info.appName);
        image.setImageDrawable(info.icon);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```